# `Variable not in scope` in simple a function

Tags: haskell

Consider the next piece of code -

```
pvp::Board->Int-> IO ()
pvp board player = do
  player1choice <- prompt $ ("Player " ++  (show (player + 1)) ++ ", it's your turn:")

  if player == 0 
    then let newboard = (put board X (read player1choice)) in newboard
    else let newboard = (put board O (read player1choice)) in newboard

  case newboard of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid move."
    Just board' -> putStrLn "Valid move."
```

For `case newboard of`, i get `error: Variable not in scope: newboard :: Maybe a0`. whats the reason for this?

Comment: Reading this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35198897/does-mean-assigning-a-variable-in-haskell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I have not the whole haskell file I can only give an educated guess - but you are having newboard only in scope of your `if .. then .. else` expression

This should be correct assuming `put` is returning a new `Board` - and has nothing to do with `State`:

```
pvp :: Board -> Int -> IO ()
pvp board player = do
  player1choice <- prompt $ ("Player " ++  (show (player + 1)) ++ ", it's your turn:")
  let newboard = if player == 0
                   then put board X (read player1choice)
                   else put board O (read player1choice)
  case newboard of
      Nothing -> do
        putStrLn "Invalid move."
        -- playGame b
      Just board' -> putStrLn "Valid move."
```

### Note (unrelated to your problem)

You should avoid `read` it will crash your program if someone enters an invalid input - say a letter where you expect something numeric. better use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.6/docs/Text-Read-Extra.html#v:readMaybe)

Comment: Thank you for your time answering my question, but with this fix i get ` No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal \`1' ` (4th line)

Comment: I don't know what your line 4 is you need to show your whole file - otherwise  I cannot help you. But nevertheless this is an unrelated problem to the current one - better open a new question for that one.

Comment: I mean 4th line in the piece of code in your answer

Comment: As I said, I cannot help you `Board` is not known to me also the definition of `put` and `prompt`.