# No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal `1' in if

Tags: haskell

Consider the next piece of code -

```
pvp :: Board -> Int -> IO ()
pvp board player = do
  playerchoice <- prompt $ ("Player " ++  (show (player + 1)) ++ ", it's your turn:")
  let newboard = if player == 0
                   then put board X (read playerchoice)
                   else put board O (read playerchoice)
  case newboard of
      Nothing -> do
        putStrLn "Invalid move."
        pvp board player
      Just board' -> putStrLn "Valid move."
```

When i try to compile the script i get the following error-

```
 No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal 1'
 In the second argument of (==)', namely 1'
```

This is how i call pvp -

```
main = do
  playGame emptyBoard
  where
    playGame board = do 
      game_choise   <- prompt "Choose game type: (1) PvC (2) PvP"
      if game_choise == 1
        then putStrLn "1"
        else pvp board 0
```

Comment: As I already mentioned in a comment to my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47094727/630160) - you need to include the definitions of `put`, `prompt` and `Board` to provide some context.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong part of your code.  The error message does not match the code you've included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my most likely fix (guess) would be

```
main = do
  playGame emptyBoard
  where
    playGame board = do 
      game_choise <- prompt "Choose game type: (1) PvC (2) PvP"
      if read game_choise == (1 :: Int)
        then putStrLn "1"
        else pvp board 0
```

Comment: or `if game_choise == "1"`, I guess

Comment: It would be "safer" on the other hand it might lead to unexpected runtime behavior - since I don't know if prompt returns the string including newline. I would do something like `case readMay gameChoice of Just (1 :: Int) -> ..`.